# Build Machine Unit Tests

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build-automation, microsoft-fakes

What are the requirements to run automated builds through TFS, where the solution contains unit tests that use [the Microsoft Fakes framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx)?

I have a build machine working now with VS 2010 and .NET 4.0. I know that VS 2012 Ultimate could be installed. How would I target VS 2012 rather than 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS 2012 and Visual Studio 2012 are currently required on the build server to build and run tests using Fakes.

Comment: Are there any resources that you can point me to about migrating from 2010?